# Will the Google web crawler stop crawling and indexing pages that take longer than 2.8 seconds to load?

Tags: google, google-search, googlebot

I just received this statement from my client:

> our PR company works on ads for us and they spoke to a representative
>   from Google . they said after 2.8 seconds the Google web crawlers stop
>   indexing your page.

This is the first time I have heard that. What is about these 2.8 seconds? It surprises me.

Basically the client now wants the page to load within 2.8 seconds (completely I guess). You see my problem?

**EDIT** the clients page is actually a WordPress page.

we can lower the response time by like 1 second when using php 7 (which will eventually go live at some point)

http://ironscales.com/ is the clients page. He is using a lot of plugins with a lot of JS requests.

Comment: All of the page HTML should load in less than 1 second. As for other resources, you will find that a lot of e-commerce and publication sites load much slower than 2.8 seconds. Google seems to be fine with that. You can use Google Chromes Developer Tools to check the sites actual load times and what resources may be loading slowly. I suggest that any site load as quickly as possible for the user, otherwise, the user may bounce back. There is no actionable information in this question for us to help you. If you can edit your post and include a screen shot of load times, we may be able to help.

Comment: With Quality Hosting and Site Optimisation its easy to get under 1 second page rendering. My own site is manages 0.5sec (500ms) when using region to region: https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/d3yT8J/https://www.bybe.net/

Comment: But... to add... Google has officially said that sites that respond slower will suffer reduced rankings, they have not said they will not index pages. You get notices about your site being slow in Webmaster Tools (Console). So either your client or the Google rep is mistake... because without seeing official news about this I call it out and say its absolute RUBBISH, because pages and sites can become slow at times if traffics spike or there is technical problems somewhere else on the internet that is causing slowdown.

Comment: Slow sites and slow pages can prevent the amount of things that get indexed due to each crawl having an allocated time... but this has been the case since the land before Google.

Comment: i added an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2010 [Google announced](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/using-site-speed-in-web-search-ranking.html) that page loading speed was a ranking factor.  As far as I am aware, Google has never put an official number on how  many seconds your site needs to load in.   Rather they say:

> Currently, fewer than 1% of search queries are affected by the site speed signal in our implementation

After this announcement, many web site owners tried to optimize for speed and reported how their rankings changed.  We found that:

1. Google only penalizes very slow sites.   Their slow page penalty only applies to the initial page load (before images, and scripts).   If the initial page load is greater than seven seconds, Google will downgrade rankings.
2. Optimizing the site speed for users can have positive SEO implications.   This is probably due to usability ranking factors rather than to direct measurements of site speed by Google.  Getting the page to load above the fold and be ready to use in under 3 seconds can improve search engine rankings.   Further improvements can have positive user experience results (such as better conversions) but don't tend to lead to better search engine rankings.

The 2.8 seconds that you state is very similar to the 3 seconds that I have seen confirmed experimentally.    However, this has never been a statement directly from Google as far as I am aware.  Google will certainly crawl and index sites that take longer than 2.8 seconds to load.